# htaccess with wildcard option to move htm or html extension back to the site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect any URL ending in .htm or .html back to the domain. The site I'm working on was previously static and now it's moved to Wordpress however I need to make sure they do not lose customers coming from previous links indexed by Google.

Site moving from static HTML to dynamic (Wordpress)

Code that I have tried but I'm not so knowledgable with regex
Redirect 301 /*.htm https://domain.co.uk

The above did not work and shows 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Regards Tom